# Excel merge similar rows and sum cells

Tags: excel, vba

what would be the best way to merge similar rows (only order number letter different a4;a6;a8 and produced quantity) and sum (produced quantity e4;e6;e8) cells? This is how excel table looks
 [image]

Clarification: 
Here is the output I'm looking for
[image]

Rows 4;6;8 are the same except Order column (one letter added on 6 and 8) and Produced Column (different produced quantity). Rows 4,6,8 are merged and produced quantity is summed. Rows 6,8 is hidden or deleted.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "merge similar rows"? Perhaps a sample of what you expect the output to look like would help.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: @BruceWayne Hi. I have added clarification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is an example that could solve your problem:

```
Sub test()

i = 1
produced = 0
While Cells(i, 1) <> "" Or Cells(i + 1, 1) <> ""
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then

        produced = Cells(i, 5)

        j = 1
        'second loop to add up every line with the same order, then suppress the lines
        While Cells(j, 1) <> "" Or Cells(j + 1, 1) <> ""
            If Left(Cells(j, 1), 7) = Left(Cells(i, 1), 7) And i <> j Then
                produced = produced + Cells(j, 5)
                Cells(j, 5).EntireRow.Select
                Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                j = j - 1
            End If

            j = j + 1
        Wend

    End If

i = i + 1
Wend
```

Comment: Thank you @Bitoubi for help. In full version of my excel sheet produced column is 20, so I have changed Cells(j, 5) to Cells(j, 20). and my order number is 123456-7 or 123456-78 (eight or nine symbols lenght) so I have changed Cells(j, 1), 7 to Cells(j, 1), 9 but still can't get it working. Maybe you know what wrong could it be? and btw, workbook has from 200 to 500 rows.

Comment: Thank you, with a little bit of modification, I've managed to make it working. :)

Comment: Nice - I highly suggest though that you [remove the use of `.Select`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros).  The line would just be `Cells(j,5).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp`

Comment: @BruceWayne Yes, I have removed select. Posted my full solution, which helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is the modified @Bitoubi code which helped me:

```
Sub RemoveSplitOrders()
i = 1
produced = 0
While Cells(i, 1) <> "" Or Cells(i + 1, 1) <> ""
    If Cells(i, 1) <> "" Then

        produced = Cells(i, 20)

        j = 1
        'second loop to add up every line with the same order, then suppress the lines
        While Cells(j, 1) <> "" Or Cells(j + 1, 1) <> ""
            If Left(Cells(j, 1), 8) = Left(Cells(i, 1), 8) Or Left(Cells(j, 1), 9) = Left(Cells(i, 1), 9) Then
                If Cells(j, 2) = Cells(i, 2) And i <> j Then
                    produced = produced + Cells(j, 20)
                    Cells(i, 20).Value = produced
                    Range(Cells(j, 20), Cells(j + 1, 20)).EntireRow.Delete Shift:=xlUp
                    j = j - 1
                End If
            End If

            j = j + 1
        Wend

    End If

i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```